# Cross-Validation, how to actually implement the concept

Tags: cross-validation

I have 100 samples from a normal distribution with variance equal to 1, and mean equal to 0. I have selected 90 samples randomly out of the 100 and i have estimated their mean (the average of the 90 samples), based on the assumption that the variance is the same as that of the original sample.

My question is, how do I compute the likelihood of the remaining 10 samples under the fit? Do I have to estimate the mean of the remaining 10 and compare it with the mean of the selected 90?

I have just started studying statistics and would appreciate any inputs.

Comment: [One place to start](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/crossvalidation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is a standard holdout set.  Test on big subset A and validate on small subset B. Cross validation is different.

For 10 fold cross validation you will split the data into 10 subsets of 10 each.

For 10 iterations choose one subset of 10 to be the validation set and train a model on the remaining 90 instances and record performance, RMSE for example, on the validation set.

Average the 10 performance metrics and this is your estimate of how the final model will perform on out of sample data.

The final model you deploy will be built on all 100 instances.

Comment: No problem.  A big benefit of cross validation compared to a holdout is also that you will get a standard deviation of your estimate.  This comes in very handy when you are comparing different algorithms and techniques.  A model with the same mean performance but less variance may often be more desirable.